# Thumbnail component error in react

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, react-component, webpack.config.js

I have added the thumbnail component into my project. I got to see the following error in my project after adding it. The error is shown in the following image.

[image]

Here's my webpack.config.js file code which might help you on understanding the issue. There's a loader to be specified there. I don't know what's the specified loader for this. Anyone faced the same issue?

Any help regarding this issue?

```
**/*webpack.config.js*/**

/* eslint comma-dangle: ["error",


{"functions": "never", "arrays": "only-multiline", "objects":
 "only-multiline"} ] */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const pathLib = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/HelloWorld/startup/registration',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, '../app/assets/webpack'),
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        use: {
          loader: 'imports-loader',
          options: {
            shim: 'es5-shim/es5-shim',
            sham: 'es5-shim/es5-sham',
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,  
        include: /node_modules/,  
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

And Here's the code where I called the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Thumbnail from 'react-native-thumbnail-video';

class VideoThumnail extends Component {
   render() {
     return(
       <div>
         <Thumbnail url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgj3D5-jJ74" />
       </div>
     );
   }
}

export default VideoThumnail;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a web application, you cannot use libraries specified for react-native. Thats only for react-native mobile applications.

If you want such mudules for web application i guess you can try something like, [react-video-thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-video-thumbnail)

Comment: Yeah but having an error after adding it to my project - **Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded**